# My website is blank upon deploying with Nginx server and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, is-empty

I am deploying an application for a company. I wrote the nginx configuration, the Docker file, and connected via SSL certificate to the proxy server. When I open the URL where the application should actually be visible, the code is accessed, but the website is blank.

I really investigated the routing problem towards the project files and much more, but I did not obtain anything significant.